# yoga.h/YGEnums.h not found

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

yoga.h/YGEnums.h not found the project has all the files still having the same issue when building the app for ios. I have tried all the solutions regarding the yoga which is on StackOverflow but still the  issue did not solved and running with the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

- Remove your /ios and /android folders
- Run `$react-native upgrade` to generate /ios and /android folders again.
- Run `$react-native link` for any native dependency.
- Finally run `$react-native run-ios` or anything you want.

Hope this helps.